# Automatic email message after manual user approval

Tags: php, plugin-development

Is there a way or a snippet that can be created to automatically send an automatic email to users who we manually approve stating there account has been approved.

To go a little in-depth about this - User's are able to sign up to our website and the information is sent to the website, we have a custom plugin that display certain information the user entered, the information is displayed through using Advanced Custom Fields. In the customised plugin section we have "login allowed" checkbox, i want it so when i check this and click update user, the email is sent.

The email would be automatically retrieved from the wordpress's default "Basic information" section if possible. Any guidance / clarification & feedback is majorly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
add_action(‘acf/save_post’, ‘my_save_post’);

function my_save_post( $post_id ) {

// create some logic here to check if you are editing a user
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow == ‘user-edit.php’) {

//get the value of the field
$value = get_field(‘login_allowed’,$post_id);

// check if the checkbox is filled
if ( ! $value ='unchecked' ) {
        return false;
    }

    $value == 'checked'{

// Company information
        $email = “removed”;
        $name = “removed”;

        //get user's email
        $user = get_user_by('email', $useremail);
        if ($user) {
        $details['email'] = $user->user_email;


        // email data
    $to = $useremail;
    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = ‘From:‘ . $name . ‘ <‘ . $email . ‘>’ . “\r\n”;

        // send email
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a custom Action Hook that is triggered whenever the user is updated.

For example, when custom meta fields are updated in WordPress, some action hooks such as: updated_{$meta_type}_meta, updated_postmeta, etc.

So if you're using the ACF plugin, you can hook into the 'acf/save_post' action hook. The action hook lets you do something before or after the custom field are being updated. For more info on using the acf/save_post, [click here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/).

Next, you can now send the email to the user using the wp_mail() function.

Based on the code you have provided, I made some refactoring:

```
add_action(‘acf/save_post’, ‘my_save_post’);

function my_save_post( $post_id ) {

// create some logic here to check if you are editing a user
// Keep an eye on this pagenow check to see if it's correct
// Use wp_die( var_dump( $pagenow ); to debug
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow == ‘user-edit.php’) {

//get the value of the field
$value = get_field(‘login_allowed’,$post_id);

// Remove this, just here for debugging
// wp_die( var_dump( $value ) );

// check if the checkbox is filled
if ( $value == 'unchecked' ) {
        return false;
}

        // Company information
        $email = “removed”;
        $name = “removed”;

        // Debug: I see $useremail variable, is it set somewhere?

        //get user's email
        $user = get_user_by('email', $useremail);
        if ($user) {
        $details['email'] = sanitize_email( $user->user_email );


        // email data
    $to = $useremail;
    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = ‘From:‘ . $name . ‘ ’ . “\r\n”;

        // send email
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );

        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for your reply - I actually forgot to put my snippet code i shall edit the post and add it in now, any guidance is appreciated on it.

Comment: Hello @YxngLBZ, I have updated the my example with your code being refactored

Comment: As I've explained, if nothing is happening, try using `wp_die( var_dump( $variable_here ) );` to inspect the code

Comment: Regarding your message about $usermail - I was unsure how to retrieve the email automatically form the basic information section so i just created it, i believe it may not work though.

Comment: If you're editing the user profile, there's always a reference to the `User ID`, `User Email` or `User Login`. Mind you, as stated on the ACF official doc, you cannot retrieve some editable object by hooking into the `acf/save_post` action hook. So now, you will have to use the native `metadata update` action hooks that gets fired every single time a meta field is updated.

Comment: Right now, am trying to think through the meta type object. If you're updating the user, this probably should be a `user meta type`.  You'll find most the WP meta field features on `/wp-includes/meta.php`. The meta field action hooks to look at include the following: `updated_{$meta_type}_meta`, `update_{$meta_type}_meta`.

Comment: Also, look at the `$_GET` global variable, if you're editing a user on the `user-edit.php` page, there should be a reference to the user you're editing.